# Android - Espresso testing - Close and app and then re-open it?

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my espresso test, I close the app by using "device.pressBack()".
I then want to re-open the app, in a certain Activity, but I'm not quite sure how to do that, since I don't even have a context at this point. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

OK, got it. You define a rule in your test class:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> myActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class, true, false);
```

Then, after you used device.pressback(), you can use this to open that specific Activity in your app:

```
myActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
```

Comment: I got this. androidx.test.espresso.NoActivityResumedException: Pressed back and killed the app

Answer (score 1):

This will close your app and re-open again.

First, execute code bellow. To navigate back into the last activity.

```
            pressBackUnconditionally();
```

Then execute the next code. It will close your application or activity

```
 @Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

            activityRule.finishActivity();
```

Finally, open application/activity using below code

```
 activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
```

A full snippet here below

```
        pressBackUnconditionally();
        activityRule.finishActivity();
        activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity test rule is deprecated.
You can do this using the following code.

```
activityScenarioRule.scenario.close() 
ActivityScenario.launch(YourActivity::class.java, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

After you close your app, a `NoActivityResumedException` exception is thrown so you will have to catch it.

After that, relaunch your activity by using an `ActivityTestRule` of type `MyActivity` as Cookienator have said.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> myActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class, true, false)

myActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
```